# Flash Builder failed to connect to running application

Tags: debugging, flash-builder

In Flash Builder 4.7 i get the following error message

```
The Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running application. 
Ensure that:

For in-browser applications, you are running the debugger version of Flash Player.
For network debugging on a mobile device, you have a reliable network 
connection to the device, and port 7935 is open on your machine's firewall.
```

**I have tried**

- Reinstalling Flash Builder
- Starting a new project
- Reinstalling Java
- Restoring system point
- Reinstalling Firefox and flash debugger version for it. verified at this site https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html
- All of the steps listed "https://forums.adobe.com/thread/672635" in every post

  - every related post on stack overflow
- Plus some others.

Please if anyone has any more ideas, I'm completely lost as to what to do, If I can't get somewhere on this by this afternoon then I'm probably going to just commit to spending a few days reformatting my drive and reinstalling everything.

Comment: maybe this would help: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007814/flash-content-wont-open-in-firefox-64-on-windows-10/46214713#46214713)

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it did work for me to solve a different issue I had after I had reformatted my computer and gotten my set up working.