# Flash content won't open in Firefox 64 on Windows 10

Tags: flash, firefox

Beginning this week, Flash content won't open in Firefox. Instead I receive the message "To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 11.1.0 or greater is installed." I have successfully opened Flash content in Firefox continuously before this week.

Nothing that I know of has changed on my system. I am running Windows 10 1703 build. Firefox and Flash player are the latest.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both the regular and debugger versions of Flash player 26.0.

Comment: I just used Firefox at: **https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed** and it showed Flash, what error does that site give you? (show a screen grab image, if possible).

Comment: This site works for me. I guess the problem is isolated to my Flash Builder dev environment. Perhaps the 26.0 player doesn't work with Flash Builder without some setup.

Comment: What has Flash Builder dev environment got to do with Firefox? Make an SWF then in a **Notepad** display it using `<embed>` code as shown in that above link (in fact, just copy paste all that code and replace that URL with your own SWF file name). Save the text file as `test.html` (save at same place/folder as SWF file) and open in Firefox? Did it display Flash content?

Comment: @VC.One Because Firefox is (or perhaps was) the only browser that could run a debugger player and load local content. No, the above test does not work. A week ago it would have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start and debug flash in FlashBuilder, Flashbuilder launches the SWF as file://- URL. The Current Version of Firefox only allows flash to run on http:// or https://.

You can force Firefox to allow file-URLs.
Just type about:config in the Firefox adress bar. Search for item "plugins.http_https_only" an change the value to "false".

Comment: Your answer needs a  lot of upvotes!!! This one got me stuck for an hour with the famous 57% "waiting to connect to the running application" problem. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: What about other browser? Like Chrome and IE?

Comment: This solution does not work for Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS